# How to append when get more data from server using combine in swiftui

Tags: swiftui, combine

I use combine with code:

```
Publishers.CombineLatest($schoolId, $offset)
        .filter { $0.0 > 0 && $0.1 >= 0 }
        .removeDuplicates(by: { (prev, current) -> Bool in
            prev.0 == current.0 && prev.1 == current.1
        })
        .debounce(for: .seconds(0.3), scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
        .map { APIClient.default.request(forRoute: GetMoreCommentRouter(params: ["schoolId": String($0.0), "offset": String($0.1)], method: .get), forType: [CommentModel].self)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .replaceError(with: [])
            .handleEvents(receiveSubscription: { [weak self] _ in
                self?.isLoading = true
                }, receiveCompletion: { [weak self] _ in
                    self?.isLoading = false
                    self?.currentText = "No comment here."
                }, receiveCancel: { [ weak self] in
                    self?.isLoading = false
                    self?.currentText = "Error from server!"
            }) }
        .switchToLatest()
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .assign(to: \.commentList, on: self)
        .store(in: &disposeStore)
```

when I change offset, the API call again. I want to append new data from server to commentList.
But I don't get any way. I'm a newbie in combine. please help me!

Comment: I don't understand - you want to append to `commentList` instead of assigning to it? You should then use [`.sink`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/anypublisher/sink(receivecompletion:receivevalue:)) and in its closure append the newly received values

Comment: Also, you should avoid `.assign(to:,on:)` when assigning to a property on `self` because that could cause a [retain cycle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/assign(to:))